I sent a BTC transaction from Bitcoin Core to an exchange, but it doesn't show up on the blockchain
yesterday I sent a BTC transaction from Bitcoin Core to an exchange, but it doesn't show up on the blockchain, and the funds have already been deducted from my wallet. What happened? How can I resolve this?

Double check that the address you sent the coins to was the correct one. If it is correct, it may just take some time for the transaction to show up in the mempool/be confirmed.

发送货币的地址是正确的，一般需要多长时间，谢谢您
